# Can't bookmark specific network locations in Nautilus

Tags: networking, nautilus

I am using a NAS server to keep all my music, pictures and video on, and would like to have them as easily accessible in Nautilus as possible.

So naturally, I edited the 'Music', 'Video' and 'Pictures' links on the left on Nautilus under 'computer' to my custom locations on the network. This worked fine until I restarted Ubuntu, when I noticed all the links had disappeared. I assume this is because the locations aren't local, and don't fit the 'computer' criteria.

So I tried adding them via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (add bookmark), and all this did was create a link to the root of the network drive under bookmarks, not helpful.

So, is there any way I can add links to these folders to the left side of Nautilus?

To mount the NAS, I edited fstab with the following using cifs

```
//NAS IP /home/henry/henrydocs cifs uid=henry,username=henry,password=x 0 0
```

Comment: Whether you can bookmark a network folder depends on how it is mounted on your local computer. Please edit your question with information about how you are connecting the NAS to the Ubuntu machine. Are you using Samba, NFS, CIFS, FTP, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links you see under *Computer* are created automatically by reading the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

[image]

Edit that file to point to the right need path and the link changes will survive the reboot.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the bookmark is not added, but this method enables the bookmark icon (or Ctrl-D), which was grayed out earlier.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers looking to create bookmarks to remote locations that will not default to the root folder or home folder of the remote user:

- Create the bookmark
- Edit your bookmarks (ctrl+b) and specify the remote path in the location field

Comment: Thanks, I had missed the fact I could edit the bookmark location!

Comment: Thanks, this is a very odd quirk. You can't drag certain items like symlinks into the Bookmarks left sidebar. But you can create a placeholder bookmark, and then manually edit Bookmarks with `ctrl+B`. smh